# Update Javascript WordAPI in older version of Microsoft Office

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm currently using Microsoft Office Professional in version 16.0.4266.1001, and it has Word JavaScript API 1.1.

I'm wondering if I can update Word JavaScript API to 1.3 without updating my Microsoft Office Professional?

In that case I would have Microsoft Office Professional version 16.0.4266.1001 and Word Javascript API 1.3.

Thank you for reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New features in the Office.js API have dependency on the updates in the product. so you need to update office if you want to use the 1.3.  BTW we are now in Builds 16.0.8229, so your build is quite old, I strongly recommend you to update. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not; the JS APIs and the supporting host code are intricately connected.

See https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/office-js-versioning